# List not being recognised as a list when read from text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am reading lists from a txt file but when I read them back in and saved to a variable Python recognizes it has a string and not a list. Is there any way around this?

```
def makereport():
    with open('quizdb','r') as quizdata:
        for line in quizdata:
            print(line)
            print(line[1])
```

Output:

```
['maths(easy).txt', 'joh17', 'C', 0.0, 0]
'
```

As you can see when I print by index position it is printing the character and not the actual position(object) in the list

Comment: They aren't "lists in a text file". It's **text**.The answer is not to simply dump the string representation of an object to a text file and [call it serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization). Use one of the many built-in serialization formats, e.g. `pickle` for arbitrary Python types, or  `json`, which looks like a good choice in this case.

Comment: I just thought once the text had been saved to a variable it would recognise the format of the text as a list due to the square brackets.

Comment: Otherwise, you are going to have to parse this yourself. This looks like you **could** just use `eval`/`ast.literal_eval`, but instead, you should really just use an existing serialization format. I suggest JSON.

Comment: It's *not a list*. It *looks* like a list-literal, but it is a string. You need to grok the difference between a string and source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot read in anything from a file other than strings. You need to use a python library for that, like `ast`:

```
>>> ast.literal_eval("['maths(easy).txt', 'joh17', 'C', 0.0, 0]")
['maths(easy).txt', 'joh17', 'C', 0.0, 0]
```

This will interpret the string as an actual `list`, where you can access indices:

```
>>> ast.literal_eval("['maths(easy).txt', 'joh17', 'C', 0.0, 0]")[0]
'maths(easy).txt'
```

Look into `json` or `pickle` for more intuitive ways for storing data. It is generally better to use one of these methods rather than actually storing the raw string representation, as clients can simply call `json.loads` rather than having to evaluate your text file.